C# : how to read/copy file and let other process read/write/delete the former file
Is there a way to copy file or its content and let other process write or delete the file while being read by my process? I use Filestream and StreamReader methods but even if I set the FileShare parameters to RW and Del, the other process sometimes throws an exception about R/W to file. It is exception I/O 130. I do not have source code of other process/program nor can I change its functions.
This should normally work, or not?
 private void auftragChange(object sender, string fileName)
 {
     UInt32 result;
     int okParts = -1;
     int iter = 0;
     string Auftrag = null;
     bool isUsed = true;
     string[] fLines;
     Thread.Sleep(3000);

     while (isUsed || iter < 11)
     {
         if (iter = 10)
         { 
             LogMessage($"CHYBA: Soubor je využíván jiným procesem: {fileName}"); 
             return; 
         }

         Thread.Sleep(500);
         isUsed = !isFileInUse(new FileInfo(fileName), iter) ? false : true;
         iter++;
     }

     using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite|FileShare.Delete))
     using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
     {
         fLines = sr.ReadToEnd().Split(new[] { '\n' });
     }
}

Oh, and the method AuftragChange is called by FS Watcher.
Thanks for your opinion/advice.

Does it make sense to allow that a file can be deleted while you are reading it's content?

Maybe you could first create a copy of the file with a unique name, then you can read and move it afterwards and don't need to worry about other threads/processes deleting or changing the original file.

@Tim - its about priority, the second process is a master, When I do not get the content in one cycle in my own process, it is not a probllem, I get it in the second cycle (when the file change again). But the master process should never throw an exception, it is more important for other functions.   About  the file copy - isnt it the same? When I am copying the file and master process want to read/delete wouldnt there be a conflict? If not, it is solved.

if you can ensure that the second process also uses FileShare.ReadWrite it should be no problem

As I wrote in main post, I cant.  Another way woud probably be some sniffing of traffic between server and terminal - server changes the file I am watching and terminal (master) use the file. If I can trace the traffic through network and catch the right string (a new production order in my case) it will be soved too, but it is quite new level for me - I like learning new things.

Related.
